# CSS Fixed Header only showing 2 rows

Tags: css, html-table

I'm using the following CSS to hold my table column headers to the top of the page:

```
table thead tr {
        display: block;
}

table tbody {
        display: block;
        height: 75px;
        overflow: auto;
}
```

The thing I can figure out is why the table is only showing 2 rows (depending on the content height of the rows).

If I adjust the height under `table tbody` then the header drops down even further, leaving a white space between the top of the page and the start of the header (which I, obviously, don't want).

Hopefully, this is a simple one as I am pulling out my hair... and there's not much left.

**EDIT**

Here's the relevant markup (I had to make it generic). There are 30 columns and ~1200 rows.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

table thead tr {
        display: block;
}

table tbody {
        display: block;
        height: 75px;
        overflow: auto;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<table width="190%" border="1" cellpadding="6" style="border-collapse: collapse">
                <thead>
                        <th>COLUMN  1</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  2</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  3</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  4</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  5</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  6</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  7</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  8</th>
                        <th>COLUMN  9</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 10</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 11</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 12</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 13</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 14</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 15</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 16</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 17</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 18</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 19</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 20</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 21</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 22</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 23</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 24</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 25</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 26</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 27</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 28</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 29</th>
                        <th>COLUMN 30</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 01</td>
                                <td>ROW 01</td>
                                <td>ROW 01</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 02</td>
                                <td>ROW 02</td>
                                <td>ROW 02</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 03</td>
                                <td>ROW 03</td>
                                <td>ROW 03</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 04</td>
                                <td>ROW 04</td>
                                <td>ROW 04</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 05</td>
                                <td>ROW 05</td>
                                <td>ROW 05</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 06</td>
                                <td>ROW 06</td>
                                <td>ROW 06</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 07</td>
                                <td>ROW 07</td>
                                <td>ROW 07</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 08</td>
                                <td>ROW 08</td>
                                <td>ROW 08</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 09</td>
                                <td>ROW 09</td>
                                <td>ROW 09</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                                <td>ROW 10</td>
                                <td>ROW 10</td>
                                <td>ROW 10</td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm also attaching an image of what I'm getting. The bottom line (highlighted by the arrow) needs to be expanded out to cover a larger area of the page.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML for the table?

Comment: Indeed. With the most obvious html to accompany this css, the problems you describe don't occur. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/f9da2u07/2/

Comment: You don't need to use `display: block` on table elements, and it will probably lead to undesired results. Tables are not forgiving. But please, provide relevant markup.

Comment: If I take out `display:block` from either of the elements, it breaks the scrolling capabilities.

Comment: With your source and your screenshot, I still can't see what problem you are talking about, sorry. The scrollable block is 75px high, as specified in the CSS. And I don't see "the header drops down even further, leaving a white space between the top of the page and the start of the header" happening if I adjust the css.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't have to be too complicated. Remove the `display: block` from your table elements. It's not necessary. The user agent already applies its own styles to these to make them behave like tables.

```
table thead tr {
}

table tbody {
  height: 75px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: If I remove both of them = No scrolling; If I remove from `table thead tr` = scrolling is there but all rows appear under column 1; If I remove from `table tbody` = row 1 spans all 30 columns and the other columns are outside the header.

Comment: Are you talking about horizontal scrolling? It works just fine. You're going to need to be much more thorough and specific if you want help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked (for me):

```
table thead tr {
        display: block;
}

table tbody {
        display: block;
        overflow: auto;
        height: 700px;
}
```

Notice that the `height` item is listed last in the `table tbody` element. Not sure why I thought about doing that but the height responded the way I wanted once I changed the order.